# class not foundexception: oracle.jdbc,driver.OracleDriver

Tags: ojdbc

I wrote a code and got this error, then I searched it in Internet and all answers were about adding jdbc literary, I did it 8n several ways according others guidance in Internet but Ithe didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you have written wrong path "oracle.jdbc,driver.OracleDriver" , replace this with 
"oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" because a path never contains a seprater.